# overlapping of text in case of variable sized elements

Tags: html, css

i was trying the code shown in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/2aWcV/

how to remove the overlap if "$number" can have any number of  digits and we dont know its size as in the number of digits as it fetched from some other file.($number is a random number generated) $number must have an opaque background so that the text underneath it doesn't show through.

The html code is:

```
<div class="body">     
<div class="variation font700 green"> 
<h2> 
overflown text must be hidden and the visible text  must be in single line
<span class="divider"> 
$number 
</span>
</h2>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Basically you just want to make whatever is bigger than the container simply not appear? Simple. Give the container a fixed width, then set it to overflow: hidden. Prevent line breaks if necessary.

Comment: the number which we get for $number must be completely visible (in a single line) and the text beside(on the right hand side) can be hidden in case it overflows... in such a case how can we fix the width??

Comment: Oooooh. I see. The text to be hidden must be behind the number. To do that, use position: absolute; and give your number a background-color. Simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/XRFDW/

Comment: This is working if we have a fixed color throughout the variation instead of a gradient.. how can i solve this for a gradient??

Comment: @Ariane im sorry error in my previous comment  text must be to the left hand side of the number (the sample given in my fiddle)

Comment: For the alignment, simply set the number's `right` to 0. For the gradient... if I were you I'd give up on the gradient. IF it can be done (and I'm not sure it can) the key lies in the number being in a container of the same size as the overlapped text's container (so the gradient fits) and it being made to only appear if under the number. Alternatively, you can use a monospace font (for example Courier New) and use JavaScript to count the number of characters on the number, and delete that same number of characters from the overlapped text. But it can only work with a monospace font.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust opacity (`opacity : 0.0`) to hide the text $number

```
.divider{
  border-left: 0.05em solid black;
  margin-left:-2%;
  opacity:0.0;
}
```

Comment: $number must be visible completely (and not part of it ). It is the text that is overlapped must be hidden .. since $number is a randomly generated number we don not know the width of it.. in such a case how can we hide the overlapped text

Comment: This is working if we have a fixed color throughout the variation instead of a gradient.. how can i solve this for a gradient??

Answer (score 0):

setting the **z-index** value of the span containing the $number to be higher than the overlapping text could be handy for you.

Comment: can u please update it in my fiddle because when i tried i didnt find any change